# Listing the revisions that are missing between two REFs in Git

Tags: git

I use this alias in `.gitconfig` to list the revisions that are missing between two REFs:

```
[alias]
    missing = "!f() { test $# -gt 1 && { first=$1; second=$2; } || { first=HEAD; second=$1; }; git rev-list $first..$second --oneline | sed -e 1i'\\ ' -e '1iOnly in '$second: -e 's/^/    /'; git rev-list $second..$first --oneline | sed -e 1i'\\ ' -e '1iOnly in '$first: -e 's/^/    /'; }; f"
```

The expression expanded to multiple lines for readability:

```
test $# -gt 1 && { first=$1; second=$2; } || { first=HEAD; second=$1; }
git rev-list $first..$second --oneline | sed -e 1i'\\ ' -e '1iOnly in '$second: -e 's/^/    /'
git rev-list $second..$first --oneline | sed -e 1i'\\ ' -e '1iOnly in '$first: -e 's/^/    /'
```

Example usage and output:

```
$ git missing master feature123

Only in feature123:
    4e34a98 added example for not enough tests
    f3031cb improved some good examples

Only in master:
    9a7c6dc added short example
```

Is there a better way to do this? (For example a `git` command that already does something close enough.)

Is there a better way to write the alias? The long chain of commands crammed on a single line is hard to read.